# Unwrapping a gun

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv

Im trying to get a user friendly unwrap for a weapon, ive tried many methods but they all either return complex texture maps or distorted mapping, what techniques can I use to make the unwrapping a little bit easier or more user friendly?

I made the gun in multiple parts as per real life (receiver, stock, etc)

The gun will be re-texture-able by the community so it needs to be easy to read

here are two examples of the most common problem I am facing

[image: Using Smart-unwrap]

[image: Using Hand placed seams]

[image: Seams1]

[image: Seams2]

[image: Seams3]

[image: Seams4]

Comment: You need to show us more. How mesh is looking (wireframe), where did you placed seams?  Preferably upload .blend file to: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ then you can recieve some answers.

Comment: You have way too many seams. Every 'closed' seam generates another island in uv map. Especially those seams in holes. Mesh is looking a little bit messy, ngons, tris, quads. Where you want to export this model? Game engine?

Comment: the seams are arranged so the main sides are the sides of the gun, the top, and bottom of every part, the game engine is Roblox, which supports multiple separate parts per gun, and using a single texture file for all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UV unwrapping a mesh so that others can use it for re-texturing usully means a lot of editing by hand in the UV editor.

For your gun, I would suggest that you go into side view and then use the Project from View option from the UV Mapping menu.

It makes things a little easier if you start the UV unwrapping before applying the mirror modifier.
[image]
[image]

When editing the UV islands use a grid and the enable Area Stretch from the UV properties panel.
[image]
Don’t be surprised if you find that you spend more time editing the UV’s than you spent creating the actual mesh.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer, just to clerify, this also works with asymmetrical guns?

Comment: Yes of course. Just means more work for you.
Edit mode,  Side view,  Face select mode,  select one face of the part you want to unwrap followed by the L key, that whole part will now be selected. U to open UV mapping menu and choose the Project From View option .
In the Uv editor move that Island aside so that you have an empty UV space for the next part you will be unwrapping.

Comment: In the 3D editor switch to view the opposite side and repeat the UV unwrapping. 
Do this for the other two or three main parts of the model. Then start moving, scaling and editing those islands’ in the UV space.
When you have these big parts correct you can go back to the model and start unwrapping and UV editing the smaller parts.