# How to UV Unwrap a complex shape?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I need some help. My Tommy gun is very very intricate, and I've never really textured before - and the tutorials I follow are very confusing for me.

Can someone help me step by step?

[image]

<s>Oh and, as an addendum, can someone tell me how to turn off the transparent view in edit mode? It's making me see past where I want to click.</s>

Comment: Hi, please only ask one question at a time. You are welcome to ask as many separate questions as you need as separate posts. Also, please be specific in what aspect of the unwrapping you are having trouble with. At the moment it is a very broad question which is less suited to this site.

Comment: Well, my unwraps are very messy and hard to understand (using smart UV unwrap). What's a better way to do this then?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71235/unwrapping-a-gun

Comment: Do you want to paint the UV Map associated texture directly .... or paint the 3D object? If you are painting a texture on a 3D Mesh object within Blender, it may not be 100% necessary to understand every detail of the UV Map.  If you are using a non Blender tool please state so.  I can often work with a casual glance at the UV Map.  It might be more important to understand color painting techniques on a 3D Object.  The level of detail and closeup can also affect your question.

Comment: You wrote ... Can someone help me step by step? This is reminiscent of a tutorial request.  Tutorial requests are not the emphasis of this site.  Perhaps watching and working with the tutorials you have seen already 5 more times will remove the stated confusion.  It would be more interesting for you question to state ... I have created a texture multiple times and I still have this particular defect [x], which is shown in the image.

Comment: There is a great tutorial on this by Blender Guru modeling an anvil. Here is the link. https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/2018/1/17/creating-an-anvil-full-series. Part 5 is a very good video explaining the whys. He does talk about painting and the smart uv unwrap and suggest his method which I like because it is strategic in nature. Take a look at it.